# Can I compute in SQL operations on HAVING without calculate them before on SELECT?

Tags: sql, having-clause

I have something like

```
product:                                     Sales:
pk       unitPr                         Fk         Qty
1         5                              1         50
2         10                             2         20
3         15                             3         90
                                         1         36
                                         2         21
```

And I want to find only the products that have the Sales SUM(unitPr * Qty) < 1500 and how many they are.

so i suppose is something like:

```
 pk       countPk
  1         2
  3         1
```

right?
I tried this:

```
 SELECT count(*) As countPk, pk
 FROM product, sales
 WHERE pk=Fk
 GROUP BY pk
 HAVING SUM(unitPr * Qty) < 1500
```

But I'm not sure, cause I don't think I can use HAVING operator on a column that I do not have, but I do not want to create it, i only want pk and conutPk on SELECT.

Comment: You can use it.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: there are some problems with the syntax... the old-school comma operator for join should be replaced with `JOIN`, join predicates could be moved to `ON` clause, all column references should be qualified with the tablename or a table alias.

Comment: @spencer7593 ok, sure you're right about that.I did't notice but wrote about `having`  clause which's the main point of interest for the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can.  However need to learn how to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, table aliases, and qualified column names:

```
SELECT p.pk, count(*) As countPk
FROM product p JOIN
     sales s
     ON p.pk = s.Fk
GROUP BY p.pk
HAVING SUM(p.unitPr * s.Qty) < 1500
```

Comment: Ok thanks! For the standard join syntax the professor used the shortest one, but u are absolute right, this is definitely more correct!!!

Comment: @HugoB, if you aspire to be a programmer, you may also want to practice spelling "u" as "you"! And your professor sounds like he's a number of decades behind, because it is not generally considered legitimate nowadays to use the so-called ANSI-89 join syntax (in which a FROM clause specifies multiple tables separated by one or more commas), and it's surprising that such syntax is being taught in an educational setting.